# php - mysql - change timezone not working

Tags: php, mysql

I tried below code

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 
$ok = inputs("SET timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles'");
$ok = inputs("INSERT INTO `table` (`date`) VALUES ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); ");
```

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is still printing my server time.It is ignoring the timezone I set.Can some one tell me where I am wrong? thank you.

Comment: just insert time from php not form sql
like 
$ok = inputs("INSERT INTO `table` (`date`) VALUES (".time()."); ");

Comment: I inserted php timestamp but it results in 0000-00-00 00:00:00 , can you tell me correct format

Comment: my date column time is "timestamp"

Comment: just print date before and after timezone to check timezone is settled in php or not 
you are using datetime type so you must use 
date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s') to insert date

Comment: date is printing as 2015-12-07 21:42:30 , but when I update in mysql it changes to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 , maybe my default column type is "timestamp"

Comment: just change it to datetime and try again

Comment: hey thanks its working now.. but when i want to review past 24 hour result how to use that date , I tried SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` >= 2015-12-08 05:51:23 , It fails before it was `date` >= DATE(NOW()) and it was working

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= '2015-12-08 05:51:23'

Comment: You will have a lot less issues if you handle all timestamps in the database as UTC and only in the presentation layer convert to appropriate timezones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set time zone of MySQL

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+8:00'; //Your timezone
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';//Your timezone name
SET @@global.time_zone='+00:00';//Your timezone
```

For check current timezone :-

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone;
```

Comment: I added inputs("SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles'");
 , but still it prints server time for  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+8:00'; //Your timezone
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';//Your timezone name
SET @@global.time_zone='+00:00';//Your timezone